# QFontCombobox (Qt 4.7) missing fonts

Tags: qt

I am developing a Qt application and i am using a QFontCombobox that must list all fonts,the application will be used by designers and they have a lot of fonts installed. I was notified that many fonts are missing in the combobox. I read the documentation  and the combobox by default should load all fonts.
I need a solution or  at least some tips about why fonts could be missing and how could I load them. The application must be cross-platform so it would be better to avoid calling native libs if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
QStringList QFontDatabase::families ( WritingSystem writingSystem = Any ) const
```

function to see what font families are recognized by Qt. If the list is somehow incomplete you can add fonts with

```
int QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont ( const QString & fileName ) [static]
```

function.

Comment: i tested this and I get the same result as in the combo box, I am now waiting to see if the person with the missing fonts is missing them in the windows registry(that mean that the font are not installed for the user so are not accessible in Qt)

Answer (score 2):

The QFontCombobox does not display fonts but font families. See the Font Sampler example in qtdemo/Painting for how to enumerate all fonts in a tree.